# how to bind stl queue push function to a std::function?

Tags: c++, queue, bind, std-function

I tried this

```
{
    std::function<void(int)> push;
    queue<int> myqueue; 
    push = std::bind(static_cast<void (queue<int>::*)(int)>(&queue<int>::push), &myqueue,std::placeholders::_1);
    push(8);
}
```

but it is not working

Comment: Use a lambda expression instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `queue<int>`, [`push`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/push)'s parameter type is supposed to be `const int&` or `int&&`, so you should change the `static_cast` to match the type.

E.g. from

```
static_cast<void (queue<int>::*)(int)>(&queue<int>::push)
```

to

```
static_cast<void (queue<int>::*)(const int&)>(&queue<int>::push)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o5WrS9mHql0fBf6p)

Answer (score 6):

The easier way to do it, is using a lambda function

```
{
    queue<int> myqueue;
    auto push = [&myqueue](int param) { myqueue.push(param); }; 
    push(8); // myqueue - should be still reachable as it's captured by reference into a lambda capture lust 
}
```